# Trouble accessing a local process in another docker container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to connect to a RabbitMQ docker container from PHP. 
The error that I'm getting is `Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known'`. I think this is an issue with how I point my program to the RabbitMQ process.

The snippet of code that I think is causing the error is

```
$connection = new AMQPStreamConnection(getenv('MESSAGE_BROKER_HOST'), 5672, 'guest', 'guest');
```

The environment variable I'm accessing is defined in .env as

```
MESSAGE_BROKER_HOST=amqp://rabbitmq
```

I'm not very used to docker, but I was under the impression that this should work since the process that this code runs on has RabbitMQ linked in the docker-compose file as "rabbitmq".

Comment: are you using custom networks in docker-compose file?

Comment: That would be defining networks: frontend: .... backend: ... etc in the docker-compose, right? If so, then no, I am not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MESSAGE_BROKER_HOST` env should be `rabbitmq` without `amqp://` because [phpamqp-lib](https://github.com/php-amqplib/php-amqplib) does not support DSNs.

If you'd like to deal with real DSN look at [enqueue/amqp-lib](https://github.com/php-enqueue/enqueue-dev/blob/master/docs/transport/amqp_lib.md).

The code would look like:

```
<?php
use Enqueue\AmqpLib\AmqpConnectionFactory;

$factory = new AmqpConnectionFactory('amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672/%2f');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach looks fine. The only problem that I can think of, is the insufficient permissions of `guest` user. The default `guest` user of RabbitMQ can only be accessed from localhost. Although insufficient permissions shouldn't throw `unknown service` error.

Try creating a new user may be that will fix the problem.
For details about the permissions of the guest user, you can see this link:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

Comment: I don't think so. When I run a php script to test RabbitMQ from outside of a dockercontainer, it works with the parameters 'localhost', 5672, 'guest', 'guest'.